# Convert string to dateTime for mySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, datetime

I'm a computer science student and I have been stumped on part of my assignment. We have to parse an XML file and save it in a mySQL database. The problem I have run into is that there is an element in the XML file called **pubDate** that has a string that is formatted like this:

> Mon, 04 Nov 2013 11:08:58 -0600.

I have looked on multiple websites and have not been able to find any way to convert that string to dateTime.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

**Example #1 DateTime::setTimeZone() example**

**Object oriented style**

```
$date = new DateTime( '2008-02-07 16:45:58', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('D, d M Y G:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Output is like this

```
Thu, 07 Feb 2008 16:45:58+12:00
```

Please see this link also https://www.php.net/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try **strtotime**() function to convert to unix time stamp and then **strftime**() to convert to mysql date format

Answer (score 0):

try strtotime() function for php, if your date time is store in varchar, char or text in mysql  use mysql STR_TO_DATE() function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functionality provided with PHP's new [Date/Time class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). As long as you have the originating format of the string, you can easily convert it to an object and then back to whatever string format you need.

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("D, d M Y h:i:s P", "Mon, 04 Nov 2013 11:08:58 -0600");
```

Then export it as you see fit.